fetchMock.get changes endpoint?
I have an api call:  getFoo whose path is /mypath/subpath/foo and setup as a GET http call:
async getFoo(requestParameters: fooRequest, initOverrides?: RequestInit): Promise<runtime.ApiResponse<Array<Foo>>> {
        const headerParameters: runtime.HTTPHeaders = {};
        console.log(`calling GET /mypath/subpath/foo`);
        const response = await this.request({
            path: `/mypath/subpath/foo`,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: headerParameters,
            query: requestParameters,
        }, initOverrides);
        console.log(`returned from GET /mypath/subpath/foo`);
        return new runtime.JSONApiResponse(response, (jsonValue) => jsonValue.map(FooFromJSON));
    }


I have a MOCK, so if I'm working in a development environment where I cannot reach out to my api servers I can still get mocked data for a response to my call.
In my mock, I have two endpoints:
fetchMock.get(`express:/mypath/subpath/foo`, async() => {
 console.log(`called MOCK for /mypath/subpath/foo`);
});
 and
fetchMock.get(`express:/mypath/subpath/all`, async() => {
 console.log(`called MOCK for /mypath/subpath/all`);
});

I'm expecting the Mock for /mypath/subpath/foo to print out my console.log that I'm using the mock.
I tried stepping through this with devtools:
I step through the break points.  The order is:
First step:  http GET /mypath/subpath/foo
Next step:   fetchMock.get(express:/mypath/subpath/all) : expecting /mypath/subpath/foo
Next step:    http GET call returns
If I remove subpath from the GET call, so it's just /mypath/foo ... and change the mock to match on /mypath/foo ... it matches and executes the mock.  It just doesn't seem to like the /mypath/subpath/foo, but is ok with /mypath/subpath/all.
I've also made sure that /mypath/subpath/foo is the first Mock in the file, before /mypath/subpath/all
Ideas?
